# Mysql - how can I improve this query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: `factors` and `factor_items`. `FID` is the **primary key** for `factors` and **foreign key** for factor_items.

Sometimes I need to see the latest `factor` row and its corresponding rows on `factor_items` table. How can I achieve this? I know I should do a `JOIN` query on these tables but I don't have any idea for the `latest row(max FID)`:

```
SELECT * FROM factors INNER JOIN factor_items ON factors.FID = factor_items.FID;
```

Comment: Is factors.FID column is autoincrement column?

Comment: @Kumar Yes my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you include a `WHERE` condition to check the max id like

```
SELECT * FROM factors 
INNER JOIN factor_items 
ON factors.FID = factor_items.FID
WHERE factors.FID IN ( select max(FID) from factors );
```

(OR) using a `order by` and `limit` clause

```
SELECT * FROM factors 
INNER JOIN factor_items 
ON factors.FID = factor_items.FID
order by factors.FID desc 
limit 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, try it out

```
SELECT * FROM factors 
INNER JOIN factor_items ON factors.FID = factor_items.FID 
WHERE factors.FID IN (select FID from factors  ORDER BY FID desc limit 1);
```